# Formst std::chrono::duration using std::formatter

Tags: c++, format, c++-chrono

I am trying to "std::cout" a decisecond time duration:

`auto loading_time = std::chrono::duration<int , std::ratio<1,10>>(12)`

How could I use std::formatter to display the duration in the form, `%H:%M:%S.%ds`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/formatter

Comment: Have you tried https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format ? What problem are you encountering?

Comment: A `formatter` is the way to add formatting for new types to the `format` interface. Not to be used directly by user code.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm quite new to programming and genuinely struggle to read the cpp references. I think I will look for a different option.

Comment: @BoP thanks that makes sense, I was so lost. I still don't know how to use it but I will probably try to find a different way to format the std::chrono::duration. Do you know how I could use std::formatter to then use the format interface syntactically?

Answer (score 2):

The format string for `std::format` is `"{:%T}"`, or `"{:%H:%M:%S}"`.  These two are equivalent.

You do not need to specify the fractional seconds in the format string.  The formatter will use whatever decimal precision is necessary to exactly represent your `duration`, or if that can't be done within 18 digits, will use 6 decimal digits to approximate it.

You can obtain other precisions by converting or truncating your input `duration` to the desired precision, using `duration_cast`, `floor`, `round` or `ceil`, or an implicit conversion if it is loss-less.

[Here are some examples.](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:time.hms.width)

If your compiler does not yet support this part of C++20, [here is a free, open-source, header-only library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that allows you to use `format` on `duration` with very similar syntax:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto loading_time = duration<int , ratio<1,10>>(12);
    cout << format("%T", loading_time) << '\n';
}
```

This works with C++11/14/17.  The output of the above program is:

```
00:00:01.2
```

Comment: I am new to c++, I do not know how to use std::formatter syntactically. There is no example provided in the [cpp references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/formatter). Do you have any idea how to apply this? I am aware I should be using %T, I have used formatters in other languages for reference.

Comment: `std::format` is new to C++ as well.  It is only implemented on Visual Studio 19.  And then only available with the /std:c++latest option: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y83sceWMG

Comment: Just realized that after: `mts.cpp:10:10: fatal error: format: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <format>
      |          ^~~~~~~~` lol resorted to:     `if (t.loading_time.count() < 10){   //loading_time in range [1,99]
        std::cout << "00:00:00." << t.loading_time.count();
    }else{
        std::cout << "00:00:0" << t.loading_time.count()/10%10 << '.' << t.loading_time.count()%10;
    }` **a pretty bad solution but I don't even care at this point**

Comment: If you would like, here is a free, open-source, header-only preview of this part of C++20 chrono: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.  I'll add to my answer how to access and use it.

Answer (score 0):

This function did the trick:

```
std::string format_deci_seconds(std::chrono::duration<int , std::ratio<1,10>> dur){
int deci_seconds = dur.count();
std::string time_str;
time_str.reserve(15);
if (deci_seconds >= 36000){ //time is over an hour
    int hours = std::floor(deci_seconds/36000);
    deci_seconds = deci_seconds%36000;
    if (hours>9){
        time_str += std::to_string(hours);
    }else{
        time_str += '0';
        time_str += std::to_string(hours);
    }
    
}else{
    time_str += "00";
}
time_str += ':';
if (deci_seconds >= 600){
    int min = std::floor(deci_seconds/600);
    deci_seconds = deci_seconds%600;
    if (min > 9){
        time_str += std::to_string(min);
    }else{
        time_str += '0';
        time_str += std::to_string(min);
    }
}else{
    time_str += "00";
}
time_str += ':';

std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << deci_seconds/10.0;
std::string sec = stream.str();

if (deci_seconds/10.0 < 10){
    time_str += '0';
    time_str += sec;
}else{
    time_str += sec;
}
return time_str;
}
```

I am aware this is probably the least elegant solution, I sadly did not know how to import a custom library.